# Flex application automation using PhantomJS

Tags: apache-flex, phantomjs

I have to automate a Flex based rich internet application. We have tried out a few options like Ranorex and RIA Test. While the GUI based automation tools (both open source and commercial) do a decent job, the test scripts are hard to maintain and often result in flaky reports. PhantomJS has worked for me in previous projects very well but I am not sure if it works with Flex. Can anyone suggest if PhantomJS works at all with Flex?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about flex, but the tag excerpt suggests that it extensively uses Adobe Flash and Adobe Air. PhantomJS doesn't support Flash or other plugins ([anymore](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10418)). There are [forks](https://github.com/r3b/phantomjs) which enable flash, but they are a little behind with the versions.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i think this might have as much to do with how you build the automation tests that makes them hard to maintain.  For instance with Ranorex instead of building 5 different recordings to test 5 different things build 15 tiny recordings that do only one thing, that can be pieced together in 5 different ways, then to maintain your scripts you just need to maintain those 15 recordings, and if all the scripts break at the same place the maintenance simply becomes ok why did that one tiny recording fail rather than ok let me maintain this suite of 5 recordings it's let me fix this one recording, and that will fix the larger recordings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We do not use any record-play back modules on principle. All of our tests are hand coded. The problem is with the tool not being able to identify certain custom controls.

Answer (score -1):

Try and use Testcomplete identifies most of the complex Flex controls not need for any compilation of helpers with your application libraries and if you have a team of dedicated automation engineers they should easily be able to create a reusable and maintainable GUI based automation pack around Testcomplete (vbscript)